# Why does the root user need sudo permission?

Tags: sudo

```
[root@notebook ~]# grep root /etc/sudoers
root    ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

**Question:** Why does the root user need sudo permissions? I've seen it on different UNIX OSes. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: `sudo` != root.

Answer (score 26):

So that they can (from the `man` page):-

*execute a command as another user*

`sudo` isn't limited to allowing regular users to execute a command as root.  Root can run a command as another user with:-

```
sudo -u bloggs <command>
```

Note that root will not need to supply the user's password.

Comment: su -c '<command>' bloggs

Comment: Yes, it is a surrogacy method and root is merely a very common usage.

Answer (score 10):

Suppose you have a script that does a bunch of things without needing special privileges, and then a single privileged thing that it does through sudo.

If you want this script to be useful for root too, it is convenient that this final sudo command won't refuse working because "you're root; root is not allowed to sudo".

Configuring this in sudoers instead of hardcoding an exemption for root in the sudo binary reduces the complexity of the security-critical code in sudo (however slightly), which is always a good thing.

Comment: And besides, I've more than once accidentally started an admin-level command with `sudo` while I already *was* root, just because it's ingrained into my muscle memory...

Answer (score 4):

The reason given in the original sudo manual (sorry no online version I know of) was for logging active commands wherever possible when logged in as root.